# Padding makes horizontal scrollbar to appear

Tags: html, css

Looks like I did something wrong, because I have this "bug" over and over again... When I add left or right padding to an element my whole page became more then 100% width! I got a horizontal scroll bar... Please check out my code on the link below and tell me what common mistake I do every time. Thank you!

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utujm2f6/)

```css
body, html{margin:0; padding:0; font-family: 'open sans','helvetica'}
#wrapper{display: block; float: left; max-width: 100%; width: 100%;}
#parser{display: block; width: 100%; padding: 100px 10%;}
#parser .field{display: block;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parser">
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="vk_string" class="field">
      <input type="submit" name="vk_send" value="go!">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `width:100%;` or apply `box-sizing:border-box;`.

> **`box-sizing: border-box;`** The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Thanks. I added box-sizing:border-box; and worked.